# Test to see if a port on a network is open?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I plan on flying soon, and I want to see if I can get free wifi on the flight. I want to scan the network for any open ports and see if I can connect to my VPS and set up a SOCKS5 proxy for my browser. Is there any way to scan the network I'm connected to see which ports are open? And once I do, how do I connect to my server through SSH on that port?

Comment: If you're talking about scanning the free provided network, you don't have to scan for open ports on a network, and probably shouldn't be invading other people network with such scans of networks you don't own or have authority.  To connect to your VPS.  To connect to your VPS, you would only need the Public IP provided to you by your VPS provider and connect to the VPS via that IP and the port you set up for the service.

Comment: Uhm, is `ssh user@hostname` not enough for some reason to test connectivity? For non-standard port numbers use the `-p` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was `nmap`. It lets me scan a network by just running `nmap -A <IP of router or website>` where you then wait up to like 30 seconds and you get an output like

`$ nmap -A askubuntu.com`

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-27 21:22 EST
Nmap scan report for askubuntu.com (151.101.1.69)
Host is up (0.017s latency).
Other addresses for askubuntu.com (not scanned): 151.101.65.69 
151.101.129.69 151.101.193.69
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE        VERSION
80/tcp  open  http-proxy     Varnish
|_http-server-header: Varnish
|_http-title: Did not follow redirect to https://askubuntu.com/
443/tcp open  ssl/http-proxy Varnish
| http-robots.txt: 77 disallowed entries (15 shown)
| /posts/ /posts? /amzn/click/ /questions/ask/ 
| /questions/ask? /search/ /search? /feeds/ /feeds? /users/login/ 
| /users/login? /users/logout/ /users/logout? /users/filter/ 
|_/users/filter?
|_http-server-header: Varnish
|_http-title: Ask Ubuntu
| ssl-cert: Subject: 
commonName=*.stackexchange.com/organizationName=Stack Exchange, 
Inc./stateOrProvinceName=NY/countryName=US
| Not valid before: 2016-05-21T00:00:00
|_Not valid after:  2019-08-14T12:00:00
|_ssl-date: TLS randomness does not represent time

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at 
https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 20.62 seconds
```

This is what I needed, so thanks me!